# How to convert a string of numbers into a vector of numbers and then sum it?

Tags: r

I want to convert some numbers in a string into individual numbers and then sum it. I tried the following:

```
a <- as.character("100 + 100 + 50,00 + 100 + 50 + 5,000 + 
      100 + 100 + 100 + 100 + 100 + 100 + 
      20,000 + 3,000 + 20,000 + 100 + 1,300")


#remove comma
b <- gsub(",", "", a)

# replace + with comma
c <- gsub("+", "," , b, fixed = T)

#sum it
d <- as.numeric(c)
```

> Warning message:
>   NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: `sum(scan(text = gsub(",", "", a), sep = "+"), na.rm = TRUE)` for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the comma, we can use `eval` with `parse` to directly evaluate the string.

```
a <- as.character("100 + 100 + 50,00 + 100 + 50 + 5,000 + 
      100 + 100 + 100 + 100 + 100 + 100 + 
                  20,000 + 3,000 + 20,000 + 100 + 1,300")

b <- gsub(",","",a)

eval(parse(text = b))
55350
```